# Cant load interop.PRNADMINLib in c# on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, dll, interop

Hi have a project that uses the functions in prnadmin.dll, in order to the use them I reference the interop.PRNADMINLib.dll It all works fine on 32 bit but I get the following error on 64 bit:

> Could not load file or assembley 'Interop.PRNADMINLib, version=1.........

I have registered the prnadmin.dll on the 64 bit system using regsvr from the SysWOW64 folder.

Is this ever going to work? If so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your project specifically targets the 32 bit environment, don't use the "any" configuration.  See if that helps.